# How does temperature affect the ability of materials to catch fire and keep burning?

Tags: temperature, combustion

While I'm asking a general question, and will appreciate all answers, the reason for asking this is that I am making a game that will include temperature, among other features, and I'm wondering how temperature interacts with properties related to fire spreading.

Comment: Isn't flammability simply the *ability* to burn/catch fire? That is, it's a *property* of the substance that is *irrespective of temperature*.

Comment: @KyleKanos Ah, so it's completely independent of temperature? Does that mean that a piece of wood in absolute zero would catch on fire and keep burning just as it would in any other condition?

Comment: Yes, it's independent of temperature. No, it probably wouldn't burn in those conditions, *but that doesn't mean wood isn't flammable!*

Comment: @KyleKanos I get your point. Though I think that's a bit pedantic :P

Comment: Call it pedantic, if you want, but all I've done is point out that you are asking a nonsense question (of the form "how does the intrinsic property of A depend on B$\neq$A?").

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, I couldn't ask a better question without knowing what I know now. Maybe it was a nonsensical question, but I do not regret asking it, I have gained new knowledge. Perhaps I should have asked in a less professional-oriented place than here, but meh.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably most interested in one of the following:

[Flash point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_point): lowest temperature at which a material will ignite in a normal atmosphere **with** an external source of ignition.

[Autoignition temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature): lowest temperature at which a material will spontaneously ignite in a normal atmosphere **without** an external source of ignition.

For example: if a material is at a temperature above its flash point, it can be ignited and will burn. If it is below, it will not.

Comment: You should also consider the minimum energy needed for ignition, and also the fact that materials change with temperature. For example, the wood : water will evaporate, some gas will be released as the temperature increases and thus the minimal energy will be lowered. For gasoline, the partial pressure of gas will increase and ignition will be easier.

Comment: Hmm, google says the flash point for wood is 300°C, how does wood catch on fire, then? Does it simply first warm up?

Comment: If you don't add any other fuel (e.g. gasoline) then yes, the wood has to heat up before it will sustain burning. If you've made a campfire before, you know that you can't just light a large log with a match-- you have to start with smaller stuff for that reason. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Solid_fuels

Comment: Mhm. That's an awesome answer, thanks. Well, the problem that I've got is that I can't subdivide relatively large objects into smaller elements, so there's no local heating above a certain scale, I suppose I might have to model catching on fire slightly differently.